# Kotlin Red Warning Codes

Tags: kotlin

Please give me solutions of this problem from my kotlin codes!
[t.message has red warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1nVF.png)
[binding.root has red warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBquZ.png)

I've tried to resolve this issue, but still have no success in addressing it.

Answer (score 0):

replace it with `val_binding`

```
RecyclerView.ViewHolder(val_binding.root)
```